# nginx serving static files too slowly

Tags: centos, nginx

I have a lightly big javascript file about 2M serving by nginx, I use `ab` to test performance, it is very very slow about 5/sec. cpu and memory usage are very low, cpu load is also low,  `interruputs` of `dstat` is high but on the contrary `interrupts` is very low in `top`, network bandwidth usage is only 13M.

result of `dstat`:

```
 ----total-cpu-usage---- -dsk/total- -net/total- ---paging-- ---system--
 usr sys idl wai hiq siq| read  writ| recv  send|  in   out | int   csw 
  0   0  99   0   0   0|   0     0 | 449k   13M|   0     0 |  14k 3985 
  1   0  99   0   0   0|   0    75k| 450k   13M|   0     0 |  13k 4096 
  0   0  99   0   0   0|   0     0 | 456k   13M|   0     0 |  14k 4063 
  0   1  99   0   0   0|   0  4096B| 449k   13M|   0     0 |  14k 4099 
  1   0  99   0   0   0|   0    41k| 451k   13M|   0     0 |  14k 4090 
  1   1  99   0   0   0|   0     0 | 431k   13M|   0     0 |  13k 4015 
  2   3  94   1   0   1|   0    37k| 442k   13M|   0     0 |  14k 4732 
  0   1  98   0   0   1|   0     0 | 455k   13M|   0     0 |  14k 3937 
  0   1  99   0   0   0|   0  4096B| 441k   13M|   0     0 |  14k 4061 
  0   0  99   0   0   0|   0    32k| 452k   13M|   0     0 |  13k 3895 
  0   0  99   0   0   1|   0     0 | 449k   13M|   0     0 |  14k 4025 
  0   1  99   0   0   0|   0    75k| 449k   13M|   0     0 |  14k 4087 
  1   0  99   0   0   0|   0     0 | 459k   13M|   0     0 |  14k 4068
```

result of `top`:

```
top - 01:30:22 up 32 days, 15:55,  4 users,  load average: 0.06, 0.04, 0.05
 Tasks: 209 total,   1 running, 207 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
 %Cpu0  :  0.4 us,  0.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 98.4 id,  0.5 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.4 si,  0.0 st
 %Cpu1  :  0.5 us,  0.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 98.6 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.5 si,  0.0 st
 %Cpu2  :  0.4 us,  0.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
 %Cpu3  :  0.4 us,  0.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 98.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.9 si,  0.0 st
 KiB Mem :  8009116 total,  2860992 free,  2376112 used,  2772012 buff/cache
 KiB Swap:  8257532 total,  6995792 free,  1261740 used.  5289404 avail Mem
```

nginx config:

```
user  root;
worker_processes  4;


events {
    worker_connections  10240;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" "$request_time"';

    access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;


    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        location ^~ /static/js {
                alias /root/static;
        }
    }
}
```

result of `ab` test:

```
ab -c 50 -n 1000 http://172.16.10.252/static/js/mapcube.js
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1430300 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking 172.16.10.252 (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
Completed 300 requests
Completed 400 requests
Completed 500 requests
Completed 600 requests
Completed 700 requests
Completed 800 requests
Completed 900 requests
Completed 1000 requests
Finished 1000 requests


Server Software:        nginx/1.18.0
Server Hostname:        172.16.10.252
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /static/js/mapcube.js
Document Length:        2067001 bytes

Concurrency Level:      50
Time taken for tests:   177.033 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      2067254000 bytes
HTML transferred:       2067001000 bytes
Requests per second:    5.65 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       8851.632 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       177.033 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          11403.56 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0   44 230.9      4    3010
Processing:  3356 8729 2531.8   8484   27916
Waiting:        1   20  96.9      5    1465
Total:       3360 8773 2537.0   8503   27921

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%   8503
  66%   9628
  75%  10282
  80%  10667
  90%  11868
  95%  13021
  98%  14240
  99%  16293
 100%  27921 (longest request)
```

nginx access log:

```
172.16.13.163 - - [09/Aug/2021:01:32:32 +0800] "GET /static/js/mapcube.js HTTP/1.0" 200 2067001 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" "-" "10.531"
172.16.13.163 - - [09/Aug/2021:01:32:32 +0800] "GET /static/js/mapcube.js HTTP/1.0" 200 2067001 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" "-" "9.056"
172.16.13.163 - - [09/Aug/2021:01:32:32 +0800] "GET /static/js/mapcube.js HTTP/1.0" 200 2067001 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" "-" "4.995"
172.16.13.163 - - [09/Aug/2021:01:32:32 +0800] "GET /static/js/mapcube.js HTTP/1.0" 200 2067001 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" "-" "7.615"
172.16.13.163 - - [09/Aug/2021:01:32:33 +0800] "GET /static/js/mapcube.js HTTP/1.0" 200 2067001 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" "-" "12.134"
172.16.13.163 - - [09/Aug/2021:01:32:33 +0800] "GET /static/js/mapcube.js HTTP/1.0" 200 2067001 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" "-" "10.562"
172.16.13.163 - - [09/Aug/2021:01:32:33 +0800] "GET /static/js/mapcube.js HTTP/1.0" 200 2067001 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" "-" "6.037"
172.16.13.163 - - [09/Aug/2021:01:32:33 +0800] "GET /static/js/mapcube.js HTTP/1.0" 200 2067001 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" "-" "7.596"
172.16.13.163 - - [09/Aug/2021:01:32:34 +0800] "GET /static/js/mapcube.js HTTP/1.0" 200 2067001 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" "-" "9.360"
172.16.13.163 - - [09/Aug/2021:01:32:34 +0800] "GET /static/js/mapcube.js HTTP/1.0" 200 2067001 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" "-" "10.697"
172.16.13.163 - - [09/Aug/2021:01:32:33 +0800] "GET /static/js/mapcube.js HTTP/1.0" 200 2067001 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" "-" "10.562"
172.16.13.163 - - [09/Aug/2021:01:32:33 +0800] "GET /static/js/mapcube.js HTTP/1.0" 200 2067001 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" "-" "6.037"
172.16.13.163 - - [09/Aug/2021:01:32:33 +0800] "GET /static/js/mapcube.js HTTP/1.0" 200 2067001 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" "-" "7.596"
172.16.13.163 - - [09/Aug/2021:01:32:34 +0800] "GET /static/js/mapcube.js HTTP/1.0" 200 2067001 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" "-" "9.360"
172.16.13.163 - - [09/Aug/2021:01:32:34 +0800] "GET /static/js/mapcube.js HTTP/1.0" 200 2067001 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" "-" "10.697"
172.16.13.163 - - [09/Aug/2021:01:32:34 +0800] "GET /static/js/mapcube.js HTTP/1.0" 200 2067001 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" "-" "4.924"
172.16.13.163 - - [09/Aug/2021:01:32:34 +0800] "GET /static/js/mapcube.js HTTP/1.0" 200 2067001 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" "-" "10.588"
172.16.13.163 - - [09/Aug/2021:01:32:34 +0800] "GET /static/js/mapcube.js HTTP/1.0" 200 2067001 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" "-" "13.913"
172.16.13.163 - - [09/Aug/2021:01:32:34 +0800] "GET /static/js/mapcube.js HTTP/1.0" 200 2067001 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" "-" "11.859"
172.16.13.163 - - [09/Aug/2021:01:32:35 +0800] "GET /static/js/mapcube.js HTTP/1.0" 200 2067001 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" "-" "11.748"
172.16.13.163 - - [09/Aug/2021:01:32:35 +0800] "GET /static/js/mapcube.js HTTP/1.0" 200 2067001 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" "-" "7.987"
```

ping from 172.16.13.163(ab) to 172.16.10.252(nginx):

```
ping 172.16.10.252
PING 172.16.10.252 (172.16.10.252) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.16.10.252: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.329 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.10.252: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.412 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.10.252: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=0.443 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.10.252: icmp_seq=4 ttl=63 time=0.459 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.10.252: icmp_seq=5 ttl=63 time=0.892 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.10.252: icmp_seq=6 ttl=63 time=0.443 ms
```

NIC of 172.16.10.252:

```
ethtool ens192 | grep Speed
    Speed: 10000Mb/s
```

nginx info:

```
./sbin/nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0
built by gcc 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44) (GCC) 
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --user=xxx --prefix=/home/xxx/softs/nginx --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-file-aio --with-http_realip_module --add-module=../nginx-http-flv-module
```

I have two questions:

1. `interrupts` shown in `dstat` is `14k`, is it high or normal? `interrupts` in `top` is `0.0~0.9` it seems too low, does they conflict?
2. why nginx is so slow? what should I do to improve its performance? how should I to find out the bottle neck?

PS: as `ab` use `http/1.0`, I use `ad -k` to keep alive, but it does not work.  So I change to use `siege` to test: `siege -c 50 -r 20 -H "Connection: keep-alive" http://172.16.10.252/static/js/mapcube.js` but the tps is as low as `ab` test.

siege result:

```
HTTP/1.1 200     5.56 secs: 2067001 bytes ==> GET  /static/js/mapcube.js
HTTP/1.1 200     3.13 secs: 2067001 bytes ==> GET  /static/js/mapcube.js
HTTP/1.1 200     2.68 secs: 2067001 bytes ==> GET  /static/js/mapcube.js
HTTP/1.1 200     1.41 secs: 2067001 bytes ==> GET  /static/js/mapcube.js
HTTP/1.1 200     4.71 secs: 2067001 bytes ==> GET  /static/js/mapcube.js
HTTP/1.1 200     1.17 secs: 2067001 bytes ==> GET  /static/js/mapcube.js
HTTP/1.1 200     1.67 secs: 2067001 bytes ==> GET  /static/js/mapcube.js
HTTP/1.1 200     2.51 secs: 2067001 bytes ==> GET  /static/js/mapcube.js
HTTP/1.1 200     0.62 secs: 2067001 bytes ==> GET  /static/js/mapcube.js
HTTP/1.1 200     1.12 secs: 2067001 bytes ==> GET  /static/js/mapcube.js
HTTP/1.1 200     0.21 secs: 2067001 bytes ==> GET  /static/js/mapcube.js
HTTP/1.1 200     4.29 secs: 2067001 bytes ==> GET  /static/js/mapcube.js
HTTP/1.1 200     0.23 secs: 2067001 bytes ==> GET  /static/js/mapcube.js

Transactions:               1000 hits
Availability:             100.00 %
Elapsed time:             178.83 secs
Data transferred:        1971.25 MB
Response time:              8.69 secs
Transaction rate:           5.59 trans/sec
Throughput:            11.02 MB/sec
Concurrency:               48.60
Successful transactions:        1000
Failed transactions:               0
Longest transaction:           36.69
Shortest transaction:           0.21
```

as above I use `siege -H "Connection: keep-alive"` to test 1000 requests, the `time_wait` increase rapidly to 1000, `keep-alive` doesn't work.

```
netstat -ant | awk '{print $6}' | sort | uniq -c
      1 established)
      1 ESTABLISHED
      1 Foreign
     10 LISTEN
   1000 TIME_WAIT
```

Comment: Lots of data there. The 11.02 MB/s throughput is about 90 megabits per second, so not a bad approximation to the speed you would expect with a 100 megabits ethernet link. The ping times of about 0.4 milliseconds are a little high. The shortest transaction at 0.21 seconds suggests the best you are getting is 2 megabytes in 0.21 seconds which is about 10 megabytes per second or 80 megabits per second. Are you sure there are no links at 100 megabits/sec between your source and destination?

Comment: @icarus, I use `iperf` to test actual bandwidth, `iperf -s
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 85.3 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  4] local 172.16.10.252 port 5001 connected with 172.16.13.163 port 53120
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]  0.0-10.1 sec   112 MBytes  92.9 Mbits/sec`, it shows only 92Mbits/s,  so the actual network bandwidth is the bottle neck?

Comment: Yes, it appears that the network is the bottleneck.